# How to create links to sections on the same page (but different tab) in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, r-markdown

As the question says I want to make hypertext in my page which contains 4 tabs (R Markdown file knitted as HTML).
I know this method works well within the same page that doesn't have different tabs but it didn't work with me.

Using the #id selector
`<p id="opening">Hyperlinks are utilized by a web browser to move from one page to another...</p>`

Creating a link to the selector
`<a href="#opening">Take me to the opening paragraph.</a>`

Can you please help me with that?

For example in the "home" tab I want a hypertext that directs the user to a specific section in "about us" tab

Thanks in advance

Btw, I am using HTML with R Markdown to knit the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you can do. You can assign a width and height for your `container`, then overflow: auto. Each `children` has to have the same height and same width as the `container`, therefore, if you have several children, this will overflow.

What the `hyperlink` or `tab` does when you click, it scroll to view on the said `children`.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  display: block;
  background: aliceblue;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="tabs">
<a href="#Tab-1">Tab-1</a>
<a href="#Tab-2">Tab-2</a>
<a href="#Tab-3">Tab-3</a>
</div>
<div id="Tab-1" class="child">
Tab 1
</div>
<div id="Tab-2" class="child">
Tab 2
</div>
<div id="Tab-3" class="child">
Tab 3
</div>
</div>
```